# How to intercept keystroke?

Tags: keyboard, rust, keystroke

How I can intercept keystroke in Rust without any libraries?
For example: `press W` - print: `"Press key 'W'"`.

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for but... *like in C*. In short, I do not know of any portable Rust library, so you would have to either find a portable C library or find an OS-dependent way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

> without any libraries?

There's nothing in the standard library to do this, no.

Comment: How to intercept keystroke **with** any libraries?